# Why does next raise a 'StopIteration', but 'for' do a normal return?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, stopiteration

In this piece of code, why does using `for` result in no `StopIteration`
or is the `for` loop trapping all exceptions and then silently exiting?
In which case, why do we have the extraneous `return`?? Or is the
`raise StopIteration` caused by: `return None`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.1
def countdown(n):
    print("counting down")
    while n >= 9:
        yield n
        n -= 1
    return

for x in countdown(10):
    print(x)

c = countdown(10)
next(c)
next(c)
next(c)
```

Assuming `StopIteration` is being triggered by: `return None`.
When is `GeneratorExit` generated?

```
def countdown(n):
    print("Counting down from %d" % n)
    try:
        while n > 0:
            yield n
            n = n - 1
    except GeneratorExit:
        print("Only made it to %d" % n)
```

If I manually do a:

```
c = countdown(10)
c.close() #generates GeneratorExit??
```

In which case why don't I see a traceback?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `for` loop listens for `StopIteration` explicitly.

The purpose of the `for` statement is to loop over the sequence provided by an iterator and the exception is used to signal that the iterator is now done; `for` doesn't catch other exceptions raised by the object being iterated over, just that one.

That's because `StopIteration` is the normal, expected signal to tell whomever is iterating that there is nothing more to be produced.

A generator function is a special kind of iterator; it indeed raises `StopIteration` when the function is done (i.e. when it returns, so yes, `return None` raises `StopIteration`). It is a requirement of iterators; they *must* raise `StopIteration` when they are done; in fact, once a `StopIteration` has been raised, attempting to get another element from them (through `next()`, or calling the `.next()` (py 2) or `.__next__()` (py 3) method on the iterator) *must* always raise `StopIteration` again.

`GeneratorExit` is an exception to communicate in the *other* direction. You are explicitly *closing* a generator with a `yield` expression, and the way Python communicates that closure to the generator is by raising `GeneratorExit` inside of that function. You explicitly catch that exception inside of `countdown`, its purpose is to let a generator clean up resources as needed when closing.

A `GeneratorExit` is not propagated to the caller; see the [`generator.close()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close).

Comment: `StopIteration` could probably be avoided by providing a default value for `next()`, in case of no match is found, like `next(generator_expression, None)`.