# ValueError raised before StopIteration with map(next, iterables)

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, map-function

I am writing a loop over 4 list-iterators like this :

```
it0 = iter(['foo','bar'])
it1 = iter(['bar','foo'])
it2 = iter(['foo','foo'])
it3 = iter(['bar','bar'])

try:
    a, b, c, d = map(next, (it0, it1, it2, it3))
    while True:
        #some operations that can raise ValueError
        if a+b+c+d == 'foobar'*2:
            a, b, c, d = map(next, (it0, it1, it2, it3))
        elif a+b == 'foobar':
            c, d = map(next,(it2, it3))
        else:
            a, b = map(next,(it0, it1))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

But when I run this code in Python3, I get a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)` raised before the expected `StopIteration`.

I do not want to catch `ValueError` in the `except` statement because some operations in the while loop could also result in a `ValueError` that should stop the program.

How is it that `next` doesn't raise its exception before the assignement ?

In Python2.7, `StopIteration` is raised first.

Comment: You should probably fix the error but FYI you can catch more than one type of exception without catching everything: `except StopIteration, ValueError: do_something()`

Comment: Cool cool.. Your question just led me to believe that you didn't know this. It's written as if your only choices are to catch *either* a `StopIteration` or a `ValueError`; not both. Anyway, I think Mr. Pieters might have solved the *actual* problem below.

Comment: @jDo, I just want to catch StopIteration to stop the while loop but I want the program to stop if there is a ValueError. If both are caught and ValueError can mean StopIteration, it is confusing. As you said problem solved.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin It appears that you are attempting to provide solutions to your question in the question itself. That is what *answers* are for. It is completely fine, even encouraged, to answer your own question with what worked for you.

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to be rude to Martijn Pieters who did the most of the job... Will create another answer.

Comment: @Justin: not sure that that required a full roll-back however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StopIteration` is raised, but the tuple assignment swallows this as it sees the `StopIteration` as a signal from the `map()` iterator that *it* is done producing values:

```
>>> i0, i1 = iter(['foo']), iter([])
>>> m = map(next, (i0, i1))
>>> next(m)
'foo'
>>> next(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> i0, i1 = iter(['foo']), iter([])
>>> m = map(next, (i0, i1))
>>> a, b = m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is normal behaviour; Python built-ins that expect an iterator as input always use `StopIteration` as the 'iteration is done' signal, and tuple unpacking must iterate here.

Either convert the `map()` output to a list first and test the length, use `next()` on each iterable separately and not use `map()`, or catch `ValueError` locally.

Testing the length would have to re-raise `StopIteration`:

```
values = list(map(next, (it0, it1, it2, it3)))
if len(values) < 4:
    raise StopIteration
a, b, c, d = values
```

Note that here `list()` has swallowed the `StopIteration` exception.

Catching the `ValueError` just for the `map()` operation:

```
try:    
    a, b, c, d = map(next, (it0, it1, it2, it3))
except ValueError:
    raise StopIteration
```

Not using `map()` at all by calling `next()` on each iterator individually:

```
a, b, c, d = next(it0), next(it1), next(it2), next(it3)
```

or by using a list comprehension:

```
a, b, c, d = [next(i) for i in (it0, it1, it2, it3)]
```

both of which ensure that `next()` is called before assignment takes place, rather than during assignment itself.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now. May I ask why Python2.7 behaviour is different ?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: `map()` returns a list in Python 2.7. This means it has to first *produce* that list before tuple assignment can take place, so the `StopIteration` exception is raised outside of tuple assignment iteration.

Comment: That makes even more sense ! Many thanks for a prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of Martijn Pieters answer, using list comprehension directly works :

```
a, b, c, d = [next(it) for it in (it0, it1, it2, it3)]
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413969/why-does-next-raise-a-stopiteration-but-for-do-a-normal-return?rq=1) clarifies why `for` catches `StopIteration` on the iterable but not in the body of the loop.

Another possible way, taking advantage of the `default` parameter of `next` :

```
it0 = iter(['foo','bar'])
it1 = iter(['bar','foo'])
it2 = iter(['foo','foo'])
it3 = iter(['bar','bar'])

try:
    a, b, c, d = map(next, (it0, it1, it2, it3), (None,)*4)
    while all(_ is not None for _ in (a,b,c,d)):
        #some operations that can raise ValueError
        if a+b+c+d == 'foobar'*2:
            a, b, c, d = map(next, (it0, it1, it2, it3), (None,)*4)
        elif a+b == 'foobar':
            c, d = map(next,(it2, it3), (None,)*2)
        else:
            a, b = map(next,(it0, it1), (None,)*2)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: I've incorporated that approach into my answer too; it is basically the same approach as using `next()` on individual iterators first, the point being that both avoid using a generator to postpone using `next()` until iteration for assignments.

Comment: Absolutely, it is worth noting that the `StopIteration` in the body of the `for` loop isn't swallowed though.