# Why does list(next(iter(())) for _ in range(1)) == []?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

Why does `list(next(iter(())) for _ in range(1))` return an empty list rather than raising `StopIteration`?

```
>>> next(iter(()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> [next(iter(())) for _ in range(1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> list(next(iter(())) for _ in range(1))  # ?!
[]
```

The same thing happens with a custom function that explicitly raises `StopIteration`:

```
>>> def x():
...     raise StopIteration
... 
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in x
StopIteration
>>> [x() for _ in range(1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in x
StopIteration
>>> list(x() for _ in range(1))  # ?!
[]
```

Comment: Wow, I really like the answer in the original "duplicate" question!

Comment: This is a bug, it is being addressed with [PEP 479](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) where the `StopIteration` will be converted into a `RuntimeError` so that the list doesn't incorrectly stop iterating as you are expecting it to.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen please give that as an answer so I may vote it up.

Comment: For posterity, here is the ["duplicate" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413969/why-does-next-raise-a-stopiteration-but-for-do-a-normal-return) wheaties mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming all goes well, the generator comprehension `x() for _ in range(1)` should raise `StopIteration` when it is finished iterating over `range(1)` to indicate that there are no more items to pack into the list.

However because `x()` raises `StopIteration` it ends up exiting early meaning this behaviour is a bug in python that is being addressed with [PEP 479](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)

In python 3.6 or using `from __future__ import generator_stop` in python 3.5 when a StopIteration propagates out farther it is converted into a `RuntimeError` so that `list` doesn't register it as the end of the comprehension. When this is in effect the error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
    stuff = list(x() for _ in range(1))
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 4, in x
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    stuff = list(x() for _ in range(1))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Answer (score 7):

The `StopIteration` exception is used to tell the underlying mechanism of the `list` function when to actually stop iterating on the iterable that has been passed to it. In your case, you're telling Python that the thing that has been passed into `list()` is a generator. So when the generator throws a `StopIteration` before generating any items, it outputs an empty list because nothing has been accumulated.

Comment: Wrong, the stop iteration from `for _ in range(1)` should raise the `StopIteration` for the list to finish but it doesn't, instead the `x()` raises an error that is **silently suppressed** causing it to accidentally stop. This is being changed in python3.6 and can be used with `from __future__ import generator_stop` in python 3.5. see [PEP 479](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I'm glad to see it being fixed but just because it's a bug, doesn't change the fact that that is exactly what's happening.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I wouldn't say wheaties's answer is wrong.  However, if you could post that as an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: in retrospect I think I was a little harsh on this. You are right that a generator throwing `StopIteration` is absolutely expected. But letting `StopIteration` propagate from somewhere not expecting to throw it in a way that silently exits early what ever iterator intercepts it is behaviour that should be snuffed out. ( I guess I still feel a little strong about that part :P)