# How can I make this generator loop?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to loop over a directory and load all files. I've tried using one generator to load files and another one to generate batches and call the first generator when it runs of out memory.

```
def file_gen(b):

    # iterate over my directory and load two audio file at a time

    for n in range(len(b)):
        path_ = os.path.join(os.path.join(path,'Mixtures'), 'Dev')
        os.chdir(os.path.join(path_,b[n]))
        y, _ = librosa.load('mixture.wav', sr=rate)

        path_vox = os.path.join(os.path.join(path,'Sources'), 'Dev')
        os.chdir(os.path.join(path_vox,b[n]))
        x, _ = librosa.load('vocals.wav', sr=rate)

        yield y, x

list_titles = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.join(path,'Mixtures'),'Dev'))

gen_file = file_gen(list_titles)

# second generator

def memory_test():

    memory = 0

    if memory == 0:
        a, b = next(gen_file)
        a, _ = mag_phase(spectrogram(a))
        b, _ = mag_phase(spectrogram(b))

        # calculate how many batches I can generate from the file

        memory = a.shape[1]/(n_frames*(time_len-overlap) + time_len)

    for n in range(memory):
        yield memory
        memory = memory -1

test = memory_test()
```

The second generator is where the problem is. Ideally, I would like both generator to iterate indefinitely though (the first one should go back to the beginning of the list).

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python)

Comment: unrelated: you can simplify your `os.path.join(..., os.path.join(...))` quite a bit:  `print(os.path.join("tata", "mix","dev","uuups"))  # tata/mix/dev/uuups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**itertools.cycle()**
One way you could do this is to use `itertools.cycle()` which will essentially store the results of the generator and then continuously loops them over and over.  [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

If you chose to do that, you would consume a lot of additional memory storing those results.

---

**except StopIteration**
As an alternative method, you could `try:` and `except StopIteration` for your generator yield in order to reset it back to the beginning.  Generators always raise StopIteration if you call `__next__` on an exhausted generator.

---

**Edit:** I originally linked to a wrapper function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545640/10366273) but the code in that example actually doesn't work.  Below is code that I have tested to work which is hopefully helpful. My answer here is based on the same concept.

```py
def Primes(max):   # primary generator
    number = 1
    while number < max:
        number += 1
        if check_prime(number):
            yield number

primes = Primes(100)

def primer():   # this acts as a loop and resets your generator
    global primes
    try:
        ok = next(primes)
        return ok
    except StopIteration:
        primes = Primes(100)
        ok = next(primes)
        return ok

while True:   # this is the actual loop continuing forever
    primer()
```

You'll notice we couldn't implicitly refer to our own function in order to reset itself, and we also couldn't use a standard `for loop` because it will always catch `StopIteration` before you can, by design [[more info]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413978/10366273).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see now that I repeated the question, which I am sorry for. However, I find it difficult to wrap my head around the second option. Using the code from the example, when I run next(generator_generating_function()) I keep getting keep getting the first item returned. Any advice on that?

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to still use it as a generator object? I am using a function from Keras called fit_generator that takes a generator object. When I try to use the wrapper() function instead, it throws an error: ValueError: You must specify `batch_size`

Comment: I wrapped it in another generator, which means that I'll have to calculate the amount of batches I can generate and then multiply it by the amount of epochs, but it works, so I guess I should stick with it for now

Comment: Yea I'm not sure that you can stop a generator inside of itself, I tried it a few ways and couldn't get it to work, which is why I wrapped it outside with another function.  And with that the only way would be to wrap it with a generator as well.  Interesting problem.